# ADO.Net - Map table char column to enum

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net, enumeration

In an existing SQL table a `nvarchar` column holds enumerative informations.

I now try to use a enum class to map this column using ADO.Net Entity Framework. But somehow this does not seems possible since it requires an integer column.

Does ADO EF not support enums mapped to char columns, or how to realize it allowing linq or lambda syntax on querying?

Error: `Given element assignment is invalid.`

*I am more used to hibernate orm where this is easily possible.*

Answer (score 1):

You can use private properties in your model to map your data to whatever property type you want.

```
// Model
public class Piece
{

    // Subclass Piece to add mappings for private properties
    public class PieceConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Piece>
    {
        public PieceConfig()
        {
            Property(b => b.dbtype); // needed for EF to see the private property
        }
    }

    [Column("type", TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
    private string dbtype { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public PIECE type
    {
        get { return (PIECE)Enum.Parse(typeof(PIECE), dbtype); }
        set { dbtype= value.ToString(); }
    }
}
```

Then you just need to add the configuration to your OnModelCreating method

```
modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new Piece.PieceConfig());
```